# Getting CORS when adding '}' in request param of token endpoint spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors, api-gateway

This is my gateway configuration.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin, RETAIN_FIRST
      globalcors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: '*'
            allowed-methods:
              - GET
              - POST
              - PUT
              - PATCH
              - DELETE
            allowed-headers: "*"
            
      routes:
        # Authorization server route
        - id: authorization_server
          predicates:
            - Path=/oauth/**
          uri: http://127.0.0.1:12001
          metadata:
            response-timeout: 10000
            connect-timeout: 10000
```

Everything works fine! But when adding '{' in password its getting cors error.
Below error from fornt end-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CRKw.png)

I have already tried adding encoded value for '}' -> %7D or '{' -> %7B which is working fine. But i think, this is not a good solution because, i have to work on all of special character. Please help me to find out a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally recommended to percent-encode all characters that are not part of the unreserved set (alphanumerics , "-" , "." , "_" , "~") to avoid some http related problems like CORS.

Also i see that you are sending the user credentials(username, password) in url params which is a bad practice and by that i assume that you are using **GET** http method, for such important data i'd suggest to use **POST** http method and send the data in request body.